# Run Xdebug with XAMPP, NetBeans, PHP 8.2

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I'm trying to run Xdebug on my XAMPP server (Windows 10) under PHP 8.2. I read a lot of documentations and forum and still have a problem: NetBeans not showing any error, but I can't see Variables, Call Stack, etc. Only breakpoints "works" (application paused, that's all, not more). What I'm doing wrong?

**Xdebug version:** 3.2.0-8.2-vs16-x86_64 from [download](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll)

**php.ini:**
output_buffering=off

[image]

XAMPP is installed in `D:\Programy\Xampp`. I have a few virtual hosts (working) on different ports (8000-8090), cuz https and running website preview on phone, so port 9000 isn't occupied.

**NetBeans:**

[image]

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I dont see a `xdebug.mode =develop,debug` thought XDEBUG V3 required that

Comment: XDEBUG 3 has moved the default port to 9003l, might be worth going with the change, They did it because 9000 is used by other tools and you can get conflicts

Comment: Also please update to 3.2.1, 3.2.0 has issues on Windows: https://xdebug.org/updates#x_3_2_1

Comment: As already said, you are using Xdebug 3 with Xdebug 2 configuration. Don't trust random articles and forums, they tend to be old and of course won't mention a version that did not exist when they were written, and head of the [official documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/). On a side note, please don't share pictures of text; share actual text instead.

Answer (score 2):

All your settings are still for Xdebug 2, not for Xdebug 3. Please read the upgrade guide: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide